# A query on CodeIgniter 3 is not returning result on the first loop

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have this code in model in CodeIgniter 3

```
public function get_country($countries)
{
    $collection = [];

    foreach ($countries as $key => $country) {
        $newcountry = self::get_country_id($country);
    }
}

public function get_country_id($country)
{
    $this->db->select('id, name');
    $this->db->from('countries');
    $this->db->where('name', $country);
    
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

`$countries` has values of

```
Array
(
    [0] => Philippines
    [1] => Australia
)
```

Now on the first loop, and call `get_country_id('Philippines')` method,
it doesn't fetch Philippines ID and Name,

On the second loop, and call `get_country_id('Australia')` method,
it fetches Australia ID and Name

What was the reason Philippines is not being fetched,
even when the table `countries` has record of the Philippines in it.

But when I call on `get_country()` method like,

`$ph = self::get_country_id('Philippines');`

It will fetch Philippines data.

Comment: Did you checked your data not contains any typo (e.g: *Phili**p**ines* instead of *Phili**pp**ines*)?

Comment: In **get_country** function you create an array (**$collection**) but not used anywhere and inside the loop you **pass the response of the** *get_country_id* **funtion to** *$newcountry* **variable** but also not used anywhere. Why?